# How to access parent item in handlebars helpers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a template.

```
{{#each dbModel in model}}
<h2>Database Name : {{dbModel.databaseName}}</h2>
<h3>Select Table: 
                     {{view Ember.Select
                          content=dbModel.tables
                          optionValuePath="content.tableName"
                          optionLabelPath="content.tableName"  
                          valueBinding = "dbModel.selectedTable"
                          selectBinding = "dbModel.selectedTable"
                    }}
</h3>
<h2>Selected Table is : {{dbModel.selectedTable}}</h2>
{{#each table in dbModel.tables}}
  {{dbModel.selectedTable}}       
  {{#matchTable table.tableName dbModel.selectedTable}}
      //Get fields is selected table match with table name
  {{/matchTable}}
{{/each}}
```

Now In the matchTable helper I am getting value of `table.tableName` but for `dbModel.selectedTable is undefined`.

dbModel.selectedTable is not part of actual model, I have added this to controller as follows.

```
App.DatabaseController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    selectedTable:[],
    actions: {
        cancel: function () {
         // something
        }
    }
});
```

When I change the value of select it automatically updates the information in `<h2>` tag. So it means that the value is setting and got bind properly. But for helper when I try to pass it it simply shows undefined. I searched and found that can use `../dbModel.selectedTable`. Still it is undefined. Anyone please guide.
What is the way to pass the parent to the helper in each loop?

Comment: Some thoughts: try setting the itemController, I'm not sure how you are accessing the selectedTable without it.  Try using {{with}}.  I created a jsbin to try to reproduce it, and it's working: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/fakaqoru/2/edit

Comment: thanks but it did not worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#each` loop drops you into the scope of the `tables` array. `../` places you in the scope of the `dbModel` object. To access `selectedTable` within the loop, use `../selectedTable`

Comment: thanks now it is not undefined but it is blank array[] as declared in controller. But in <h2> tag I can see the selectedTable.

Comment: It's unclear if you're still having a problem... Please consider accepting this answer and (if needed) asking a new question. :)

Comment: I have to ask new question then. :)